# Nginx git server returns error 500

Tags: windows, git, bash, nginx

I'm trying to set up an nginx remote server (with ssl) for a bare git repository, but getting `error 500` when trying `git clone https://my.domain.com/repo.git` from git bash (windows 7 machine).

My current configuration looks like this.

Nginx server config:

```
server {
  listen: 80;
  server_name my.domain.com;
  # Redirect all non-HTTPS traffic to the HTTPS version
  return 301 https://my.domain.com;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name my.domain.com;
  root /var/www/git;
  index index.html;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nxing.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

  access_log /var/www/git/git.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/git/git.error.log;

  auth_basic "Git authentication required";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/users_git;

  location / {
    client_max_body_size 0;

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend;
    fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
    fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /repo.git;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
  }
}
```

I've consulted this source for help with setting up the fcgiwrap: http://knowledgebase.cc/en/software-en/linux-en/how-to-install-fcgiwrap-to-serving-cgiperl-scripts-in-nginx/

The exact error I receive upon running `git clone http://my.domain.com/repo.git`:

> *Cloning into 'repo'... fatal: unable to access 'http://my.domain.com/repo.git': The requested URL returned error:
>   500*

This is the extract from the URL's access log:

> *1xx.xxx.xxx.xx - - [06/May/2015:17:29:02 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "git/1.9.5.msysgit.1"*

The URL's error log is empty.

I've already gone through every step and detail another person described in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/719949/centos-5-nginx-git-http-backend
but I had no success so far.

**UPDATE #1**

I've tried commenting out the fastgci parameters in the nginx server config's location setting and specifying the location url itself, resulting in this

```
location /repo.git {
  client_max_body_size 0;

  [...] commented fastcgi params [...]
}
```

The result is now that when I try `git clone http://my.domain.com/repo.git` I get the following output in git bash:

> Cloning into 'repo'...
>   Username for 'http://my.domain.com': git
>   Password for 'http://git@my.domain.com': ...
>   fatal: http://my.domain.com/repo.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

But I can reach both `http://my.domain.com` and `http://my.domain.com/repo.git` in the browser

**Update #2**

I had a loot at this website: `http://weininger.net/configuration-of-nginx-for-gitweb-and-git-http-backend.html`, which helped me solve my issue, somehow.

My final Nginx server configuration now looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name my.domain.com;
  # Redirect all non-HTTPS traffic to the HTTPS version
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name my.domain.com;
  root /var/www/git;
  index index.html;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

  access_log /var/www/git/git.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/git/git.error.log;

  auth_basic "Git authentication required";
  auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/users_git;

  location ~ ^.*\.git/(HEAD|info/refs|objects/info/.*|git-(upload|receive)-pack)$ {

    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend;
    fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
    fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $uri;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
  }
}
```

This allowed me to properly do a `git clone` and `git pull` without any errors, but `git push` would give me the following error

> Counting objects: 4, done.
>   Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>   Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
>   Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 312 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
>   Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
>   To http://my.domain.com/repo.git
>    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'http://my.domain.com/repo'

**Update #3**

Seems the `unpack failed` error was due to a permission problem. Even though I did `chown -R git:git repo.git` I could not push to the repository. But doing `chown -R git:nginx repo.git` solved it. Which I partially understand, considering that it's the `fastcgi` script doing the writing (I suppose?), which in turn is spawned by `Nginx`.

Some clarification or deeper explanation of why these settings work the way they do would be great though, in order to learn and understand things better, if anybody can.

Comment: Great, can you help me to do what you did, but in Windows ? I can find working tutorials for setup Git server using Nginx in Windows

Comment: Could you summarize your result in a single answer?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issues through a lot of (re)search and trial/error. The steps I've taken are written down in detail in the question's updates.